# How to make field required when we use k-ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, validation, kendo-ui

I have angularJS validation issue with below field , if i use ng-model its not making form $valid even the value is selected, So i used k-ng-model now this field is out of the validation scope, Any suggetion will be appreciated.

main.html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="themesList" class="required col-md-4">Themes:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="multiselect" kendo-multi-select="themes"
                    k-options="challengThemesOptions" data-text-field="'text'"
                    data-value-field="'id'" name="themesList"
                    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                    k-ng-model="challengesDTO.themesKyList" required
                    id="themesList"></select>
                    <p class="text-danger" ng-show="addChallengeForm.themesList.$touched && addChallengeForm.themesList.$error.required">Theme(s) is required</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
```